# Searchkick: how does search_index.refresh work with async callbacks?

Tags: searchkick

In a typical Rails controller, we create a `Post` model and then redirect to `posts_path`. The `index` action uses Searchkick to list Posts.

```rb
# In the model
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  searchkick callbacks: :async
end

# In the controller
def index
  @posts = Post.search("*")
end

def create
  Post.create!(post_params)
  redirect_to posts_path
end
```

However, since Elasticsearch is eventually consistent, sometimes the redirect occur **before** Searchkick/Elasticsearch indexed that record.

[Searchkick's docs](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#consistency) state that one could use `Post.search_index.refresh` to wait for the index to catch up with the new record. So one could write:

```rb
def create
  Post.create!(post_params)
  Post.search_index.refresh
  redirect_to posts_path
end
```

However, sometimes we still redirect to `/posts` without seeing the newly created record; I think that it's because we're using `callbacks: :async`, so Searchkick (and `Elasticsearch::API::Indices::IndicesClient` which is used behind the scenes) has no way to know about the queued `Searchkick::ReindexV2Job`.

If that's the case, how does one solve this use-case, which is: after the `#create` or `#destroy` action have created/destroyed a Searchkick-indexed record, redirect to the `#index` action making sure that the record is already on the index, when using async callbacks?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Based on my understanding of the docs, `.search_index.refresh` _should_ solve this. But it doesn't.

Comment: By the way, we are not using `callbacks: :async`

Answer (score 1):

> Elasticsearch::API::Indices::IndicesClient which is used behind the scenes) has no way to know about the queued Searchkick::ReindexV2Job.

Your guess is correct. It's possible that your background job hasn't been executed yet, so refreshing the search_index won't help.

To fix the issue, we need to reindex synchronously (in the same thread). Luckily you can change the [reindexing strategy](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#strategies) of Searchkick callbacks in runtime. In your scenario, I recommend to reindex synchronously via `Searchkick.callbacks(:inline)`:

```rb
def create
  # reindex synchonously
  Searchkick.callbacks(:inline) do
    Post.create!(post_params)
  end

  # ensure that all changes are reflected by the ES index
  Post.search_index.refresh

  redirect_to posts_path
end
```